# Nginx rewrite path

Tags: nginx

I want to rewrite `/flask/files/` path to `/utility/base-cert/flask/files/`. So I tried following

```
        location /utility/base-cert/ {
            proxy_pass http://base-cert/;
        }

        location /flask/files/ {
            rewrite ^/flask/files/(.*)$ /utility/base-cert/flask/files/$1 permanent;
        }
```

`base-cert` app (`http://base-cert/`) is just to serve some downloadable files.

But it is working only for txt files, but not for other files.
In the logs I see

```
10.2.19.165 - - [11/Feb/2022:21:40:52 +0000] "GET /utility/base-cert/flask/files/readme.md HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36" "x.x.x.x"
10.2.19.165 - - [11/Feb/2022:21:40:58 +0000] "GET /utility/base-cert/flask/files/base.crt HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36" "x.x.x.x"
```

In the browser I see following error

```
Mixed Content: The site at 'https://dev.example.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://dev.example.com/utility/base-cert/flask/files/base.crt' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.
```

Nginx Output

```
root@nginx-64fbcf4c54-2dkq7:/# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/frontend.dev.lightcl.conf:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=25r/s;

upstream uwsgi {
    server uwsgi:9000;
}

upstream base-cert {
    server base-cert:5000;
}

server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://frontend-dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta/;
         expires 30d;
    }

    location /api/ {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi://uwsgi;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /utility/base-cert/ {
        proxy_pass http://base-cert/;
    }

    location /flask/files/ {
        rewrite ^/flask/files/(.*)$ /utility/base-cert/flask/files/$1 permanent;
    }

    location /metrics {
        stub_status;
    }

    location /stub_status {
        stub_status;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://websockets;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /vpn/ {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi://uwsgi;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:

uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

What would be the correct rewrite ?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` so we can look at the full nginx configuration.

Comment: added output of `nginx -T`

Comment: Where is `dev.example.com` handled in the nginx configuration?

Comment: It goes to `proxy_pass http://frontend-dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta/;`

Comment: It cannot go to that block, since `https://dev.example.com` is an SSL URL, and the `server` block  for port 443 does not have any such `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: SSL termination is handled by Traefik.

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue the redirect with https URL:

```
location /flask/files/ {
    rewrite ^/flask/files/(.*)$ https://$host/utility/base-cert/flask/files/$1 permanent;
}
```

Chrome is telling that the redirect destination of the URL has `http` as the protocol, therefore it is an insecure connection.

Comment: with this files are not getting downloaded after clicking on it.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I want files to download when i click on it

Comment: Ah sorry, misread. What is happening when you click it?

Comment: Only readme file opens in the browser, for other file nothing happens i was expecting other files to start downloading.